# What are the progress bars in the creature cage?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

In the creature cage, when I'm giving treats to a familiar there's a progress bar under each of the attributes that can be affected.

What do these progress bars indicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The progress bars indicate when a certain attribute is increased. For example feeding chocolate will affect the attack attribute. Once you filled up the attack progress bar, the attribute will be permanently increased by 1. The small number between the attribute value and the progress bar (e.g. +2) indicates, how often you already increased that attribute.